# Setting y-axis label in scientific notation in veusz

Tags: plot, label, scientific-notation, veusz

How to set Y tick labels to be in scientific notation in veusz?

When using log scale for y-axis, I get 1000 instead of 10^3. Is there any way to set it to be always in scientific notation?

Down below is the y-axis I get when setting it to be in log scale. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. You have to select the corresponding axis, and under the **Formatting** options, click in the tab "**Tick Labels**". Now you can choose the "**Format**" to `%Ve`. This will force all numbers in scientific notation.